# How to delete a row in a table in Angular4 . The delete button is in each row

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, mean-stack

Component

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <th>{{ i +  1 }}</th>
    <th>{{ item.id }}</th>
    <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
    <th><button (click)="deleteItem()">Edit</button></th>
  </tr>
```

Item.service

```
deleteItem(){
let header =  new HttpHeaders();
return this._http.delete(this.api);
```

I assume i should append the delete button with id for the item. But I dont know how to implement that.

Im using the new HttpClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `item` as a parameter to `deleteItem` as

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <th>{{ i +  1 }}</th>
  <th>{{ item.id }}</th>
  <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
  <th><button (click)="deleteItem(item)">Edit</button></th>
</tr>
```

Now, depending on your actual API endpoints, you can do something like

```
deleteItem(item: any){
  return this._http.delete(this.api + '/items/' + item.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add a parameter to the `deleteItem()`  method of yours.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <th>{{ i +  1 }}</th>
    <th>{{ item.id }}</th>
    <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
    <th><button (click)="deleteItem(item.id)">Edit</button></th>
  </tr>

deleteItem(number id){
let header =  new HttpHeaders();
return this._http.delete(this.api);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the item id in delete function like

`<th><button (click)="deleteItem(item.id)">Edit</button></th>`

And get that id in your delete function as a parameter and pass to the api

```
deleteItem(itemId){
    let header =  new HttpHeaders();
    return this._http.delete(this.api);
}
```

Hope it helps